# How can I deploy one entry point for applications running cross Kubernete clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have two K8S clusters setup, one on AWS EKS, the other is on GCP. I setup a rancher server which is used to manage this two clusters. I have an application (`appA`) which is packaged in a helm chart. The application is just a rest api server created by `nodejs + express`.

It is deployed to both clusters via Rancher. After deploy, `appA` are running in the two clusters separately.

I have another application (`appB`) (running outside of K8S) which is listening on a database stream and it needs to call `appA` (in the K8S clusters) to process the change events.

My question is how I can deploy an entry point, like nginx, which will forward the `appB`'s requests to `appA`, one of the pod from the clusters should serve this request.

Answer (score 0):

- You can expose the appA Kubernetes service type as Loadbalancer.
- You can run nginx outside of the k8s, create a upstream  and add both EKS
  and GKE loadbalancers urls as backend servers.

Follow the below link

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/